# wep2py doesn't write into sql base while function is in endless loop

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have got a function that write into sql db, if I run it only one time i'ts work fine, but if it is in `while 1:`, it doesn't write anything to db

Code sample:

```
def to_db_f(f):
    for b in f:
        db.a.update_or_insert((db.a.event_id == b['event_id']), db.a._filter_fields(b))

def main():
    while 1:
        result = some_function()
        to_db_f(result)
```

Comment: Why would you write anything to a DB in a `while 1` loop?

Comment: Can you show your code and explain how you are running it?

Comment: I need to scan some websites every 10-15 second, so thats why loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your infinite while loop, the data are not committed in the DB. 
Web2py automatically commits data at the end of a function from a controller.
But in your case, the function main() never exits so, Web2py does not commit the data.

If you want to see the updated data while the loop is running, just call `db.commit()` just after `db.a.update_or_insert` :

```
def to_db_f(f):
    for b in f:
        db.a.update_or_insert((db.a.event_id == b['event_id']), db.a._filter_fields(b))
        db.commit()

def main():
    while 1:
        result = some_function()
        to_db_f(result)
```

This is explained in the [Book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#commit-and-rollback).